# k-means triangle inequality

Tags: k-means

This page explains very good how k-means works:  http://mnemstudio.org/clustering-k-means-example-1.htm

Somewhere I heard that there is some algorithms, which use triangle inequality to speed up the process. In which step, and how exactly can use triangle inequality?

Comment: [Charles Elkan. Using the Triangle Inequality to Accelerate k-Means](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~daa/courses/GSAC6017/kmeansicml03.pdf). Note please that (at least I think so) it is rather a new clustering algorithm and method, which only resembles k-means, and not a modification of the k-means.

Comment: Elkan's method is a modification of Lloyd's algorithm (the most popular way of solving k-means), and produces identical results. The acceleration simply comes from avoiding unnecessary distance computations. These computations are unnecessary because they couldn't have changed the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using triangle inequality to find the bounds to avoid redundant distance calculations.

Let x be a point and let b and c be centers.

```
Lemma 1: If d(b,c)>=2d(x,b), then d(x,c)>=d(x,b)
```

If d(b,c)/2 >= d(x,b), then d(x,b) <= d(x,c), thus no need to calculate d(x,c).

If we know an upper bound u>=d(x,c), but u >d(b,c)/2, then we need compute d(x,b) and d(x,c)

```
Lemma 2: d(x,c)>=max{0, d(x,b)-d(b,c)} >=max{0, l'-d(b,c)}
```

where l' is a lower bound of d(x,b) in the previous iteration's calculation

> The optimized algorithm is based on the fact that most distance
>   calculations in standard K-means are redundant. If a point is far
>   away from a center, it is not necessary to calculate the exact
>   distance between the point and the center in order to know that the
>   point should not be assigned to this center. Conversely, if a point is
>   much closer to one center than to any other, calculating exact
>   distances is not necessary to know that the point should be assigned
>   to the first center.

Details are in the original paper about acceleration:
Charles Elkan. Using the triangle inequality to accelerate k-means. In Tom Fawcett and Nina Mishra, editors,
ICML, pages 147–153. AAAI Press, 2003.

Other references:
Greg Hamerly, Making k-means even faster In proceedings of the 2010 SIAM international conference on data mining (SDM 2010), April 2010. [pdf](http://cs.baylor.edu/~hamerly/papers/sdm_2010.pdf)!

Comment: Can you add a precis of the paper & the specific answer to the OP's question in it here? At present this is more of a comment than an answer.